# How can I execute a query on success of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to delete some data from database. I want some functionality that when jQuery returns success I want to execute a query. I want to update a another table on success of jQuery without page refresh. Can I do this and if yes how can I do this?

I am newbie to jQuery so please don't mind if it's not a good question for stackoverflow.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function delete_comment(autoid, btn_primary_ref) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'rootbase.php?do=task_manager&element=delete_comment',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                autoid: autoid
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // I want to execute the Update Query Here

                alert("Comment Deleted Successfully");
                $(btn_primary_ref).parent().parent().hide();
                var first_visible_comment = $(btn_primary_ref).parent().parent().parent().children().find('div:visible:first').eq(0).children('label').text();
                if (first_visible_comment == "") {} else {
                    $(btn_primary_ref).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().prev().children().text(first_visible_comment);
                }
                load_comment_function_submit_button(autoid, btn_primary_ref);
            },
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.delete_user_comment', function (event) {
        var autoid = $(this).attr('id');
        var btn_primary_ref = $(this);
        var r = confirm("Are you sure to delete a comment");
        if (r == true) {
            delete_comment(autoid, btn_primary_ref);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just run another `ajax` call in the `success` of the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do database operations directly in Javascript. What you need to do is to simply make a new AJAX request on success to a php file on the backend to update given table. However this would mean two AJAX requests to the backend, both of which manages database data. Seems a bit unnecessary. Why not just do the update operation after the delete operation in the php file itself?

Comment: @Rob Schmuecker : Thanks Rob.

Comment: I can not do that because as you can see in my success i am finding the first visible div because all are visible and the user can delete the first div also. I want to update the text of first div i.e comment to db. well thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

add a server sided coded page that will execute your query.
example :
lets say you add a page named `executequery.php`.
with this code:

when you want to execute your query do the following :

```
$.post("executequery.php",//the URL of the page
{
param1:value1,
param2:value2....//if you want to pass some parameters to the page if not set it to null or {}
},
function(data){
//this is the callback that get executed after the page finished executing the code in it
//the "data" variable contain what the page returened
}
);
```

**PS :** tha paramters sent to the page are conidired like `$_POST` variables in the php page

---

there is an other solution but its **UNSAFE** i recomand to **NOT** use it.
its to send the query with the paramters and that way you can execute the any query with the same page example :

```
$.post("executequery.php",//the URL of the page
{
query:"insert into table values("
param1:value1,
param2:value2....//if you want to pass some parameters to the page if not set it to null or {}
},
function(data){});
```